# Vuex store cannot be used inside axios handler

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, console.log

I have method being successfully called by a button in my Vue component:

```
  methods: {
    goTestMe() {
      console.log(this.$store.state.lang+' 1')
      let url = 'some api url'
      let headers = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
      
      this.$axios
        .get(url, headers)
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log('here')
          console.log(this.$store.state.lang+' 2')
        })
```

The problem is that the output of this is:

```
en-us 1
here
```

When it should be:

```
en-us 1
here
en-us 2
```

Clearly, the reference to `this.$store.state` is failing in the `then()` handler of the axios call.

Why is this? How can I send data received by my axios request to the Vuex store?

Comment: Did you try to use async await? The reason it might never be called is that the function finishes too quickly. Therefore the axios request is never going to get resolved.

Comment: @FloWy This isn't the issue. He's using `then` to handle the promise asynchronously, which is basically what `async...await` translates to behind the scenes. Joseph's answer below is correct. This issue is caused by `this` being a reference to the execution context of the promise, rater than the execution context of the vue component. This happens because passing a `function(){}` expression like this, changes the context. Using an `() => {}` arrow function expression instead will make `this` refer to the vue component context.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, my bad :D

Comment: Thank you guys. If you have a good reference on understanding async/await and arrow functions in JS, I would appreciate the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you add the callback in the normal function you can't access the global object so you need to change it to an arrow function

```
 methods: {
    goTestMe() {
      console.log(this.$store.state.lang+' 1')
      let url = 'some api url'
      let headers = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
      
      this.$axios
        .get(url, headers)
        .then((response) => { // change it to arrow function
          console.log('here')
          console.log(this.$store.state.lang+' 2')
        })
}
```